# Failed to write a feedback form PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I need your help. I have a feedback form, which sends an email to a specified mailbox.
This is how my form looks like:

```
<form method=post name="feedback"> 
<div>
     <div align="center"> 
              <input class="textarea1" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off"> 
              <input class="textarea1"  type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off"> 
              <input class="textarea1" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Subject" autocomplete="off">
              <textarea class="textarea" rows="10" name="mess" placeholder="Message" autocomplete="off"></textarea><br />
              <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"></div> 
</form> 
<img id="load" src="load.gif" style="display: none;" />
        <div id="answer"></div>
```

This is how my script looks like in head of the html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#feedback").submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "feedback_lib.php",
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $("#load").fadeIn(400);
                        },
                        type: "post",
                        data: $("#feedback").serialize(),
                        success: function(answer) {
                            $("#answer").html(answer);
                        }
                    }).done(function() {
                        $("#load").fadeOut(400);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

And this is how my feedback_lib.php look like:

```
<?php

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $mess = $_POST["mess"];
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $result = 0;
    define(EMAIL_TO, "myrealmail@mymail.com");

    if ((strlen($email) < 5) or (strlen($message) < 10)) $result = 1; // длина сообщения
    else {
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $subject = "Письмо с Вашего сайта http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/";
            $header = "From <".$email.">\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
            mail(EMAIL_TO, $subject, $mess, $title, $name);
            $result = 3; //письмо отправлено
        }
        else $result = 2; // неправильный email
    }
    echo getAnswer($result);

    function getAnswer($result = 0) {
        switch ($result) {
            case 0: $answer = "";
            break;
            case 1: $answer = "<p style='color: red;'>Հաղորդագրության նվազագույն երկարություն 10 նիշ, իսկ email-ինը` 5:</p>";
            break;
            case 2: $answer = "<p style='color: red;'>Սխալ email:</p>";
            break;
            case 3: $answer = "<p style='color: green;'>Հաղորդագրությունն ուղարկված է</p>";
        }
        return $answer;
    }

?>
```

And my question is: why it doesn't work?
Where's my fault?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: # is used for "id", and not "name". Try adding id="feedback" to your form element tag.

Comment: thank you! it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `feedback` id in the form.

```
<form method=post name="feedback" id="feedback">
...........
...........
</form>
```

Comment: @Gurgen , If it works, you should accept the answer so that other people can be benefited from the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have another question. I defined not to clear the form data when there are errors like wrong email or message is shorter than 10 symbols. How can I make it to clear form data when I get answer = 3?

Comment: This one may be a good approach:  
`success: function(answer) {
 $("#answer").html(answer);
},
error: function(errorThrown){
   alert('request failed');
}`